# What is actually meant by the term 'stock browser' in web development?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm a Web Developer by profession.

Today I come across the new term 'stock browser' which I've never heard before in my 10 years of web development experience.

The text around the term 'stock browser' is as below :

> A shim differs from a polyfill, which implements a new API that is not
> supported by the **stock browser** as shipped.

From the above statement I didn't get at all the meaning and context of using the term 'stock browser'.

Can someone experienced from Web Developer community explain the meaning of the term 'stock browser' with proper context to me?

Thank You.

**Note :** *If you want I can provide you the link from where I got the quoted text.*

Answer (score 4):

It just means 'standard', cf. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stock#h3-anchor):

> 1 a : commonly used or brought forward : standard
> // the *stock* answer

See also the term ['stock Android'](https://www.androidauthority.com/what-is-stock-android-845627/), which means the unmodified open-source version, without the modifications made by phone manufacturers.